# With Python linguini how do I open a file using codecs / gzip?

Tags: python, linguini

Normally I would open a utf-8 encoded file in Python like this:

```
import codecs
f = codecs.open('file_name', 'r', 'utf8')
```

How do I do this in a linguini (https://github.com/enewe101/linguini) Task using the File wrapper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a linguini `File` resource called `my_file`, you can use

```
path = my_file.get_path()
f = codecs.open(path, 'r', 'utf8)
```

**Details**:
The `linguini.File` resource provides an `open()` method, which basically wraps the builtin `open`.  That's there for convenience.  The main *raison d'etre* of the `File` class is to transparently namespace your files -- helping you keep separate lots separate.  You can take advantage of the namespacing, while using your own file-opening functionality by calling the `File` resource's `get_path()` method.

Here's a typical usage as would be done inside a `Task`:

```
from linguini import File, SimpleTask

class MyTask(SimpleTask):

    inputs = File('path/to/dir', 'file_name.ext')

    def run(self)
        fname = self.inputs.get_path()
        f = codecs.open(fname, 'r', 'utf8')
```